# How to select button inside div tag in angular application using selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

How can I click on below element using selenium by text?

i.e "Market Statistics"

```
<button _ngcontent-c51="" class="dropdown-item" _msttexthash="1027897" _msthash="229">Market Statistics</button>
```

I tried.
`select_by_visible_text`

but it says:

> Message: Select only works on  elements, not on div

Comment: <button _ngcontent-c51="" class="dropdown-item" _msttexthash="1027897" _msthash="229">Market Statistics</button>

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `Select` only works on `elements`, not on `div` , it means there is no select tag in you `html`. You can use the `xpath` or `css` selector to locate and click on the element

***xpath***

```
   button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Market Statistics']")
   button.click()
```

***Css_selector***

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button:contains('Market Statistics')")
button.click()
```

It would be good if you provide the full `html` for the element you want to click.